# returning to a company after resigning

Tags: career-development, job-change

I worked for 7 years as a programmer for an outsourcing company. Due to the structure and mode of business I felt that if I could not be promoted to team manager (which I am not suitable for) I would always be treated as a junior. I moved to the same position in another company that has a product in the hope that it would be suitable for me. I've been there for a few months and am quiet happy there.
But while the previous company was only max 0.5 hr from home the current one is 1.5 hr (and I have small kids at home) so I am thinking of going back (I have contacted my previous CEO and at least for now the door is open)
But I am reluctant to do so because:

1. I feel I am playing with the trust of current company.
2. Am afraid the old feelings that made me leave will reawaken.
3. returning with tail between my legs

My question is has anyone any insight/experience on returning to a previous company ?

Comment: It is very likely that what made you want to leave has not changed. You like your new company, why not simply move closer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Don't like the new job .. should i go back to the old one](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/78457/dont-like-the-new-job-should-i-go-back-to-the-old-one)

Comment: I do like this new job, the things that were missing for me in the previous job are better in the new one, its just the long comute that's making me wonder. The question was more is it possible to eat chewed food.  Thanks for both answers, both are helpfull

Answer (score 3):

one of the biggest factors of how happy you are is how long your commute to work is. Personally I would either move closer to work or work closer to home. I wouldn't  go back to your previous employer though, things wont have changed.

Answer (score 1):

To the last point "returning with tail between my legs", when you return, do some loud and public complaining about the 1.5 hour commute, and everyone will understand that with such a horrible commute, they would have returned as well if they had switched to that other company.