# Don't like the new job .. should i go back to the old one

Tags: job-change

I was at a job for 2 years where I was working for a big international organization in the IT department. The work was mostly 9 to 5 with some extra hours every now and then. I was learning but not a consulting company pace but I was happy and was able to enjoy after hours with my family. The career opportunities are limited there but I was going to try and get a MBA or Masters in IT to solidify my credentials and move up.

I just started a new job and it's been 10 days. Already, I've been swamped with so much work that my life outside work has fallen into disarray. And I'm not really enjoying all the admin crap that I have to take care of at this job. There is client work plus admin work.

I want to know if it's ok to talk to my previous employer and ask for my old job back. I left on good terms with those guys and I can still get the job back. The work was fulfilling and it may take more time for me to move up but at least I'll be happy.

I also want to mention that I've changed a few jobs in the last 5 years which was mainly due to the fact that I have a certain skill which is in high demand and I moved from project to project without leaving the project in a limbo. This would be the only job where I would be leaving because I didn't like the culture.

Has anyone else had any similar experience and is it ok to go back to the old job or should I look for a new one?

Thanks

Comment: You've shown that you're not happy with what they're offering you, and now you want to go back. They might take you, but that will most likely be because they need you, not because they're too excited about having you around. And would you be, in their shoes? I would only go back as a last, and desperate resort. You're better off finding a new job.

Comment: Does your new job offer specify a probationary period?

Comment: Can you explain in some detail what sort of "admin" work is bothering you?

Comment: Questions asking for advice on what to do are not practical answerable questions - Career advice, voting to close.

Comment: I have heard of people going back to their old jobs on a few occasions, but it's been after a year or two minimum so I'm not sure if it's just because they didn't like the new one.

Comment: Look for a new job. The reasons you left the old one haven't changed in the last 10 days. Seems like this question has been asked and answered before?

Comment: i left because I wanted to give consulting a go but it's totally different from what I expected and I realized that I'm not cut out for it. I don't want to spend insane hours just working and miss out on family time.

Comment: I left because I was waiting for certain legal matters to be resolved. Not because I didnt like the work.

Answer (score 5):

10 days is extremely early to make a judgement on a new job. I would wait until at least 30 days (Maybe even recommend 90 days) to see if things smooth out. It's also too soon to judge the culture when you're brand new and have not had time to get to know people and develop a rapport.

You should also talk with your supervisor about your concerns with the extra "admin" work.

You can't reasonably assume that you can get your old job back and without *at least* a actual conversation with the old employer. Your goodwill might not be enough if they have hiring policies in place to prevent such a situation.

Comment: I agree that 10 days is too early, but but I've never had a job that I didn't know whether it would work out after 30 days. I can't imagine not knowing after 45. But I agree that he should wait.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep good point, I loosed up the recommendation in my answer a bit.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know if it's ok to talk to my previous employer and ask for my old job back

Sure it is.

It's also OK for them to not respond, flat out refuse, or offer a position with laughably bad terms.

The real question, then, is **why did you leave**? If you had grievances with your previous job, it's likely that things won't change, and you will be looking for another position within the next 6 to 12 months.

Be prepared to explain to your former employer why this won't happen (and don't expect to be offered a position if you cannot) because it will certainly be a big concern for them.